# Unit test an angular service (not factory) using Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I've been trying to test an Angular service using Jasmine following tutorials, but for some reason their examples don't here works (they suggest injecting services using the `angular.mock.inject()` method)...

This is the way I got it working, but I am afraid this is not how it should be done...

**Is this "good practice"? Why injecting doesn't work?**

I basically import the service into the test, setup my module and `$provide` the service's dependencies, and `new` the service passing it what would normally be injected...

Anyway, here it is:

```
import rolesService from './roles.service.js';

describe('Roles', () => {
  let RolesService;
  let PermRoleStore;
  let USER;

  beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module('roles', ($provide) => {
      $provide.constant('USER', {
        roles: ['SOUTIEN_ORGANISME']
      });
      $provide.value('PermRoleStore', {
        defineManyRoles: jasmine.createSpy(),
      });
    });

    angular.mock.inject((_PermRoleStore_, _USER_) => {
      PermRoleStore = _PermRoleStore_;
      USER = _USER_;

      RolesService = new rolesService(PermRoleStore, USER);
    });
  });

  it('Setup should define the roles', () => {
    RolesService.setup();
    expect(PermRoleStore.defineManyRoles).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  describe('authorize', () => {
    it('should return true if authorized', () => {
      expect(RolesService.authorize('SOUTIEN_ORGANISME')).toBe(true);
    });

    it('should return false if the user it NOT authorized', () => {
      expect(RolesService.authorize('NOT_AUTHORIZED')).toBe(false);
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the karma.config.js file just for reference:

```
'use strict';

const stringify = require('stringify');
const babelify = require('babelify');

module.exports = (config) => {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['browserify', 'jasmine-ajax', 'jasmine'],

    files: [
      { pattern: 'build/gouvernementales/app-gouvernementales.config.json', watched: true, served: true, included: false },
      'build/gouvernementales/js/gouvernementales-libs.js',
      'src/apps/gouvernementales/app-gouvernementales.js',
      'src/apps/gouvernementales/**/*.spec.js',
      'src/modules/**/*.spec.js',
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      'src/apps/gouvernementales/app-gouvernementales.js': 'browserify',
      'src/apps/gouvernementales/**/*.spec.js': 'browserify',
      'src/modules/**/*.spec.js': 'browserify',
    },

    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],

    plugins: [
      'karma-phantomjs-launcher',
      // 'karma-chrome-launcher',
      'karma-jasmine-ajax',
      'karma-jasmine',
      'karma-browserify',
      'karma-coverage',
      'karma-mocha-reporter',
    ],

    browserify: {
      debug: true,
      transform: [
        babelify,
        stringify,
      ],
    },

    helpers: [
      'src/spec/helpers/**/*.js',
    ],

    reporters: [
      'mocha',
      'coverage',
    ],

    coverageReporter: {
      dir: 'coverage/',
      reporters: [
        { type: 'text-summary' },
        { type: 'html' },
      ],
    },

    logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,

    singleRun: false,

    colors: true,

    autoWatch: true,
  });
};
```

Comment: What is the problem then?

Comment: Every tutorials mention that you should inject your services inside the `angular.mock.inject()` method, but it does not work in my case... no idea why.

Comment: I am also wondering if doing it the way it's done in my example is "good practice" or not...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do like this one

```
    import rolesService from './roles.service.js'; // it should be not included.
//Should be injected
```

**BEFOREEACH**

```
beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module(($provide) => {

      $provide.constant('USER', {
        roles: ['SOUTIEN_ORGANISME']
      });
      $provide.value('PermRoleStore', {
        defineManyRoles: jasmine.createSpy(),
      });

    });

    //you are mocking PermRoleStore and USER,so should be inject it here.
//It will get available to your service
//no need of import

    angular.mock.inject((_rolesService_) => { 
      PermRoleStore = _rolesService_;
    });
  });
```

Comment: Please check `files` property in karma.config.js and make sure the corresponding file included in list.

Comment: I've added the karma.config.js file to the description. As you can see, the app-gouvernementales.js file is already in the list of file, and is the entry point of the app. In theory, and according to all the other apps i've tested in the past, i should just be able to inject my services in to the tests using `angular.mock.inject`, but for some weird reason, it just won't work...

Comment: `roles.service.js` file is missing from list in `karma.config.js`

Comment: It's actually imported by the core module.

Comment: It should be listed there and not through any module.Thats how karma task runner koww it

Comment: Karma is processing files with browserify which bundles everything into one file... why would I need to import it again separately?